# Xpages Calendar without time slots

Tags: jquery, calendar, xpages

Any suggestion on how to create calendar without time slots on the daily, two days and weekly view ?  I looked at INotes calendar control but having found where that possible.  Also looked at jQuery FullCalendar but having difficulties on how to implement it for my requirements.

The requirement is a defined company assets scheduling for that those days, so the actual time period is not important just the day.

Lotus Domino 8.5.3 or 9.01

Thank you in advance.
Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few on OpenNTF

https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=ITWU%20adhoc%20groupcalendar

And the Teamroom template

https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8ERBUJ

You might be able to use those as the starting point and use CSS to hide the time gridlines?

Howard